# Google recognises user identity in Private mode

Tags: firefox

Today opening a link sent by a friend in a Private browsing tab I noticed that Google was immediately able to identify me and even suggest me to log on to the website.

[image]

Remarkably, Google identifies my personal user account, which I seldom use. If I need to use one of Google's services I mostly use a professional account.

Is there any way to prevent Google from identifying me in a Private browsing tab?

Comment: Private browsing shares your Chrome profile.  This has always been the case.  You can prevent that from happening by launching Chrome as a new profile.  However, at no point as Private browsing, kept Google or any major website from identifying you if you had an active cookie.

Comment: @Ramhound he's using firefox

Comment: So replace Chrome user profile with Firefox user profile.  My apologies.  What the author describes isn’t unusual

Comment: Was it the first and only private window? Did you log in in that window prior to opening the link?

Comment: (By the way, don't use blur to censor text. I can still read most of your email address on the screenshot. There's just a single letter that I can't guess. Paint over the text with a solid color instead.)

Comment: @Ramhound. I do not have Chrome installed, but thanks for the tip in any case.

Comment: @gronostaj No, this is one of various tabs (visible in the picture). The fact that you can't get all characters is good enough :). The goal is to make life difficult for bots. My personal e-mail is not that difficult to find.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa - I already addressed my mistake, Firefox and Chrome private browsing modes work practically the same, and my comment is applicable to both of them.

Comment: Google tracking you: three tabs left from seeking alpha you're reading financial times (which requires an account), which you are maybe accessing with your gmail address ?? Or maybe you have an account at arstechnica? Cookies are shared between tabs, even in a private browsing session.

Comment: @1NN I did not log on to any of the tabs you mention, but this session was a bit old and thus most likely I previously logged on to some Google service. Never crossed my mind that cookies in private mode are also shared :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how private browsing works. Private Browsing only means that Firefox will 'forget' the session that you are opening in a private window: it won't retain your history, nor cookies which are set during your private browsing session, but it will retain downloaded documents and some other information. As well, Private Browsing can access any cookies already stored on your machine. See the [firefox support on private browsing](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-use-firefox-without-history) for more about that.

EDIT: Cookies are shared between tabs of a private browsing session, so if you use your gmail address to read financial times or arstechnica (I'm looking at your open tabs), google will set a cookie for that and follow you closely through all your tabs. (end of edit)

There is no absolute way to stop google from identifying you, except maybe changing device, but there's even [cross-device tracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-device_tracking) happening.

However, in Firefox there's something called **"Containers"** which allow you to separate different accounts and identities: you can have one container for your work, another one for your private accounts and so on. In such a way you can create a "Google-free" container, in which you won't see anything directly corelated to your specific google identity. However, Google might still be able to track your online behaviour.

**What are containers?** from the [firefox support on containers](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/containers)

> Container tabs are like normal tabs however the sites you visit will have access to a separate slice of the browser's storage. This means your site preferences, logged in sessions, and advertising tracking data won't carry over to the new container. Likewise, any browsing you do within the new container will not affect your logged in sessions, or tracking data of your other containers.

To use containers, you'll have to install an add-on. Read more on [the firefox support on containers](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/containers)

Comment: Good tip on containers. Would you take a guess on how is Google exactly guessing my identity?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa - One of your other tabs that was open and/or it wasn't a fresh private browsing session (due to the numerous tabs) and you had previously logged into your google account.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa - I go with Ramhound . Cookies persist as long as you keep the private browsing window open. Instead of logging in, it can also be that you opened some link (from an email) or some bookmark which contains an access token to your Google account: Gmail can convert any link you receive from someone into a link that can track you, except if you select-copy-paste it (rather than clicking it or doing right click and 'copy link'). Take a look at the original link your friend sent to you.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa see my edit